# How can I avoid "no input files" error from sed, when run from xargs?

Tags: ubuntu, sed, xargs

I have this shell script to update IP addresses in my configuration files (any that match `$old_address_pattern` must be changed to `$new_address`):

```sh
grep -rl "$old_address_pattern" /etc \
  | xargs sed -i "s/$old_address_pattern/$new_address/g"
```

If the `grep` command finds no matching files, then `sed` will complain 'no input files'.  How can I make this pipeline succeed when the list of files is empty?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want to avoid running `sed` when `grep` produces no output, then (since you've tagged this with Ubuntu), you can give the **`-r`** or **`--no-run-if-empty`** argument to `xargs`:

> **--no-run-if-empty**
> **-r**
> If the standard input does not contain any nonblanks, do not run the command.  Normally, the command is run once even if there is no input.  This option is a GNU extension.

So your command should look like:

```bash
grep -rlZ "$old" /etc | xargs -0 -r sed -i "s/$old/$new/g"
```

(I added `grep -Z` and `xargs -0` flags, since these are supported on your platform, and they make the commands more robust to malicious filenames)

---

For platforms without `xargs -r`, then the usual solution is to pass `/dev/null` as a first filename argument:

```bash
grep -rl "$old" /etc | xargs sed -i "s/$old/$new/g" /dev/null
```

In this case, when there are no matches, `sed` will operate harmlessly on the null device.